1970s or earlier story in a fantasy/sci-fi anthology about a woman eaten by a stork
I am looking for a specific story. As I recall, I read it in an anthology associated with either fantasy or sci-fi.
I cannot recall the author or the anthology where I read it, but it probably dates to the 1970s or earlier. It was about a lonely old woman who lived by a lake/marsh and sort of struck up a friendship with a stork or heron of some sort. She kept discovering things that were not mentioned in her ornithology texts, and would write in her journal..."not true."
This next section includes spoilers but may help with identification.
Winter comes, and she is cut off from the world. She is sick and elderly, running out of food and heat, and slowly dying. When her skeletal frozen corpse is discovered in a chair on her porch, her blood-stained journal is found on her lap with a final entry..."Not true." Implying that it was untrue that these birds would never attack or eat people.
More detail: I think the protagonist's name could possibly be Agatha. 
Does this ring a bell for anyone?

I fail to see how an old woman being eaten by a bird is fantastical or science fictional.

If you're cross-posting this question onto multiple sites, it's worth mentioning; https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/22840874-short-story-maybe-horror-or-science-fiction

Yes this is being cross posted. Sorry if that is not allowed; I guess I should have checked. I am on a panel about bird horror for the upcoming NecronomiCon convention in August in Providence. When I read it I did not read horror at all except HPL, olnly fantasy and science fiction . As I recall I read it in an anthology associated with either fantasy or scifi. I wish I could be more specific.

It's perfectly acceptable to ask it simultaneously on other websites, you should just mention it is all. Perhaps in future that site will get an answer that you'll accept or rule out.
